# How to create custom cubemap images?

Tags: opengl, cubemap

I managed to use cube maps in OpenGL to get reflection and refraction effects. So far I used images from [this site](http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=Textures), however, I want to create my own set of images to use in a cubemap, the idea is just to have checker-board patter on the "floor" and the rest of a solid color.

My question is, how can I create the 6 images in order to get the cube map textures?

**EDIT**

I want to be able to achieve something like [this picture (on top)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_mapping#mediaviewer/File:Panorama_cube_map.png) but without the cube, sphere and so on.

Comment: Are you looking for a software or an algorithm / method to create them programmatically?

Comment: Yes, im looking for software

Comment: you can use `3d studio max` or `blender` or any other decent 3d modeling tool.

Comment: I was looking for a tutorial on creating cubemap images with some software,  Blender for example